# How to remove a module from my Trigger.io account

Tags: ios, module, icons, trigger.io

I'm right on the cusp of submitting my app to the App Store and I'm hitting a strange error regarding a size requirement issue for an ipad-retina.png image. Note: there are no images that bear that name included in the app, nor is this an app for the iPad.

I have traced a stock icon included in a module that is not being used in this project. I tried replacing it, but still got the error. I then tried adding a file by that name and at the requested size to my config and still got the error. When I went to delete the module, I hit a wall as I could not see anything that was possible aside from deleting my local copy—which I did and still got the error.

Considering all the things that could hold up a submission, this one seems pretty trivial but it's the only error that's being thrown and it is keeping us from submitting the app into the App Store.

Comment: Might want to send an e-mail to support@trigger.io as well since not many people on StackOverflow are using it so you will have limited help here.  Good luck with your first app!

Comment: Hey everyone, fixed my own problem. Trigger has a build_steps folder that is used to compile the app. What I didn't realize is that Trigger renames many of the assets that are used to build the app. So the error Apple was throwing back in the submission process was actually for a file that was renamed in the app build. In short, if you have an error for a file you can't find in your build, go look at the build_steps folder for a renamed asset action.